# What filepath should I use for a cron job in django?

Tags: python, django, cron

I'm setting up my first cron job in Django, following this tutorial - https://medium.com/@bencleary/django-scheduled-tasks-queues-part-1-62d6b6dc24f8

Running ***python manage.py process_emails*** manually works and the function runs.

I'm stuck at the part where I'm actually editing the crontab file:

```
*/1 * * * * /var/path/to/venv/bin/python
/var/path/to/my/app/manage.py process_emails
```

**1. How can I find the correct paths in the code above?**

The first path appears to have something to do with the virtual environment?

The second path is to the actual manage.py file, but since this will be deployed to my server on Heroku, I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to put the path on my local machine (user/workspace/myappname/etc...). Would I just put myappname/manage.py?

I'll be totally honest here: I did setup a virtual environment for this app, and it deploys and runs without issue. However, I can't fully remember how I did it, and when I look in my project directory, I don't see any reference to a virtual environment or a venv folder, etc. That may or may not be relevant here, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

**2. Where should the crontab file be?**

The tutorial says to just enter ***crontab -e*** and edit the file. I did this, and the file opened in my default editor which is Sublime. Even though my paths are wrong, I saved the file to see what would happen, and it saved in a *private/tmp/* folder. Again, since this is meant to work on deployment I don't see how that could possibly be the right place for this file.

Thank you so much for any input. If I left out any critical information, please let me know and I'll be happy to update the question.

Comment: does heroku provide any sort of environment variables that you can use to find your workspace, something like `$HOME`, etc... also where is the cron job running, on the heroku server?

Comment: @aws_apprentice Wow, you made me realize that I hadn't actually looked this up for heroku specifically to see if there was an answer. I found this article and it seems very promising! - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/scheduling-jobs-in-a-django-application-using-heroku-scheduler-13c971a22979